# How can I vectorize a for-loop running over a pandas Periodindex where I need to sort datetimes into appropriate period?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, datetime, vectorization, period

I have a Dataframe "timeseries" which has datetimes as its index and I have a PeriodIndex "on":

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


timeseries = pd.DataFrame(
        index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
            [
                "2000-01-01 12:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-01 13:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-01 14:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-02 13:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-02 18:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-03 14:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-03 20:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-04 13:00:00Z",
            ]
        ),
        data={
            "value1": [6.0, 5.0, 3.0, 7.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0],
        },
    )
on = pd.PeriodIndex(
    ["2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05"], freq="D"
    )
```

I would like to add a column to "timeseries" that contains the period in "on" that each respective datetime is in:

```
                           value1      period
2000-01-01 12:00:00+00:00     6.0  2000-01-01
2000-01-01 13:00:00+00:00     5.0  2000-01-01
2000-01-01 14:00:00+00:00     3.0  2000-01-01
2000-01-02 13:00:00+00:00     7.0  2000-01-02
2000-01-02 18:00:00+00:00     4.0  2000-01-02
2000-01-03 14:00:00+00:00     4.0         NaN
2000-01-03 20:00:00+00:00     5.0         NaN
2000-01-04 13:00:00+00:00     3.0  2000-01-04
```

So far I have achieved this with a for-loop:

```
    timeseries["period"] = np.NaN
    for period in on:
        datetimes_in_period = timeseries.index[
            (timeseries.index >= period.start_time.tz_localize("UTC"))
            & (timeseries.index <= period.end_time.tz_localize("UTC"))
        ]
        timeseries["period"].loc[datetimes_in_period] = period
```

For efficiency's sake I want to avoid loops in Python. How can I vectorize this code?

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to merge on the day? e.g. `on.to_frame().merge(timeseries.reset_index(), left_on=on.day, right_on=timeseries.index.day, how='left')` - from there you could groupby.

Comment: No, the periods are arbitrary

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "period". Why exactly are the rows timestamped `2000-01-03 14:00:00+00:00` and `2000-01-03 20:00:00+00:00` not part of any period if a period is not just a day? If I go by that logic I'd say the two rows are part of the period `["2000-01-02", "2000-01-04"]`

Comment: "period" refers to [pandas.Period](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html). The period `pd.Period('2000-1-1', freq='D')` is the day "first of January 2000". It has a start time of `Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')` and an end time of `Timestamp('2000-01-01 23:59:59.999999999')`.

Comment: The two timestamps you mentioned are not part of a period as March isn't in `on` in the example data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `.merge_asof` as [@rorshan suggested.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76034752/19355181)

If you create a dataframe of the start/end intervals:

```
df_on = pd.DataFrame({
   "period":     on,
   "start_time": on.start_time.tz_localize("UTC"), 
   "end_time":   on.end_time.tz_localize("UTC"),
})

df = pd.merge_asof(timeseries, df_on, left_index=True, right_on="start_time")

# blank out period when not inside
df["period"] = df["period"].where((df.index >= df["start_time"]) & (df.index <= df["end_time"]))
```

```
>>> df[["value1", "period"]]
                           value1      period
2000-01-01 12:00:00+00:00     6.0  2000-01-01
2000-01-01 13:00:00+00:00     5.0  2000-01-01
2000-01-01 14:00:00+00:00     3.0  2000-01-01
2000-01-02 13:00:00+00:00     7.0  2000-01-02
2000-01-02 18:00:00+00:00     4.0  2000-01-02
2000-01-03 14:00:00+00:00     4.0         NaT
2000-01-03 20:00:00+00:00     5.0         NaT
2000-01-04 13:00:00+00:00     3.0  2000-01-04
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I had tried around with merge_asof but couldn't get the blanking out to work.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer originally referred to a question which has since been edited to change the intent*

Here's my solution:

```
import pandas as pd


timeseries = pd.DataFrame(
        index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
            [
                "2000-01-01 12:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-01 13:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-01 14:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-02 13:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-02 18:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-03 14:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-03 20:00:00Z",
                "2000-01-04 13:00:00Z",
            ]
        ),
        data={
            "value1": [6.0, 5.0, 3.0, 7.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0],
        },
    )
on = pd.PeriodIndex(
    ["2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05"], freq="D"
    )


merge = (pd.merge_asof(timeseries.index.to_frame(),
                    on.to_timestamp().to_frame(),
                    right_index=True, left_index=True)
                    .drop('0_x', axis=1)
                    .reset_index()
                    .rename({'0_y':'date', 'index':'period'}, axis=1)
        )

#extracting from `on` any date which does not have a matching date in timestamp
unmatched_periods = on.to_timestamp().difference(merge.date).to_frame()
unmatched_periods[0] = pd.NaT

merge = merge.groupby('date').agg(func=lambda x: list(x))
unmatched_periods.columns = merge.columns
merge = pd.concat((merge, unmatched_periods))
merge
```

I have never used `PeriodIndex` before, and was forced to convert it to a `DateTimeIndex` with `to_timestamp`. From looking at the documentation it seems that `PeriodIndex` is intended to create dates/periods programmatically (e.g. every X days between two days), which doesn't seem to be quite what it's being used for here.

Anyway the core of the solution is to use `merge_asof` which is like `merge` but instead of requiring equal keys, it will look for the closest key. By default it will look backwards which is what we want (the closest date in `on` which is before the date in `timeseries`).

Then we use `groupby` and `agg` to get the groups.

We also need to get the dates in `on` which did not have any match in `timeseries` (in this case `2000-01-05`

Note: you say you "avoid" loops for efficiency. In theory that's a good idea, but be careful that the result you're trying to achieve (having lists as values in a column) is by itself quite inefficient, on top of pandas `groupby` also being fairly demanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works. I've been thinking about what you wrote as a note and an alternative would be to add a column in timeseries that contains the period that each respective datetime is in.

Comment: I have updated the question, but will try to find an approach similar to yours for the updated question.